Why are IPV4 sites not working and IPV6 sites work?
I am using a GPON ONT router as part of Airtel Xtreme fiber plan. We have a range extender connected to it (TP-Link TL-WA850RE). I believe this is messing up my DNS server.
If the range extender is on, sometimes (not always) certain sites stop working. Only sites like google, youtube, facebook would work but others won't. Right now, I have four devices connected to the main router, 2 Windows, 1 Mac and 1 Android. The two Windows devices cannot access Stack Overflow but others can. Not sure, if it is a Windows related issue, might have faced this on Mac as well but not entirely sure.
This issue is intermittent and occurs sometimes.
I manually set CloudFlare and Google's DNS servers in my PC settings, but still not able to access sites. (Issue is on main router, everything works fine with the same device on the extender).
C:\Users\Exter>tracert stackoverflow.com
Unable to resolve target system name stackoverflow.com.

C:\Users\Exter>ping stackoverflow.com
Ping request could not find host stackoverflow.com. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\Exter>ping 104.18.32.7

Pinging 104.18.32.7 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 104.18.32.7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\Exter>nslookup stackoverflow.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  2600:4700:4700::1111

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
* Request to UnKnown timed-out

Reconnected and got a different nslookup response (I changed the DNS servers in between as I found they were unset.
C:\Users\Exter>tracert stackoverflow.com
Unable to resolve target system name stackoverflow.com.

C:\Users\Exter>ping 104.18.32.7

Pinging 104.18.32.7 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 104.18.32.7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\Exter>ping stackoverflow.com
Ping request could not find host stackoverflow.com. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Users\Exter>nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:  one.one.one.one
Address:  2606:4700:4700::1111

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    stackoverflow.com
Addresses:  104.18.32.7
          172.64.155.249

DNS servers as in ipconfig /all
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 2606:4700:4700::1111
                                       2606:4700:4700::1001
                                       1.1.1.1
                                       8.8.8.8
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled


Update: I noticed that sites that have an IPV6 address like Google, Youtube, Facebook are working while sites that don't like Github, stackoverflow do not work.
Found something very similar: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/90r04n/very_strange_ipv4_problem_can_only_connect_to/
I am also using an extender like OP (in the above post).
These might help:

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/no-ip-addresses-are-getting-assigned.80189/
https://community.tp-link.com/us/home/forum/topic/614778


A few important questions to help get to the bottom of this: 1. Is this happening on more than one computer? This appears to be a Windows TCP/IP stack error, not necessarily a network (it might be triggered by something in the network but looks like it's Windows itself that is the issues). 2. If you do ipconfig /all does it still show your IPv4 information? 3. Can you confirm when this is happening you can still ping 600:4700:4700::1111 ? Are you able to do a Wireshark capture when this is happening. That's likely to shed a lot more light on where the underlying issue is.

@Andrew 1. It is happening on more than 1 windows device. I have never experienced it on Mac or Android yet. Other people in my home say that there net was "spotty" on a mac a few times, but they are not familiar with networking so cannot confirm that.
2, 3. As the issue is intermittent, I will have to check this when the issue occurs again and will get back to you.
